# SpriteKit App Crashing On School Machines

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, macos-sierra

### Background

I'm a high school teacher and I've written a series of midi-based music apps using SpriteKit (objective C). My latest app, which is a rhythm-based drum app designed to get them comfortable with playing drum patterns on a keyboard, crashes on school machines only and I'm not sure why. It runs fine on my machine and on private student machines. I suspect it may be something networked-related because I am writing a save file to the Documents folder. You'll see the crash report below. I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. Any help would be much appreciated.

### Crash Report

```
Process:               Drum Hero [66758]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/*/Drum Hero.app/Contents/MacOS/Drum Hero
                                       Identifier:            MF.Drum-Hero
                                       Version:               1.0 (1)
                                       Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
                                       Parent Process:        ??? [1]
                                       Responsible:           Drum Hero [66758]
                                       User ID:               1682957694

                                       Date/Time:             2017-09-13 10:33:16.940 -0400
                                       OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
                                       Report Version:        12
                                       Anonymous UUID:        B0637F3C-A9B3-E010-DB95-C3584B6B7A8F


                                       Time Awake Since Boot: 1100000 seconds

                                       System Integrity Protection: enabled

                                       Notes:                 Translocated Process

                                       Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

                                       Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
                                       Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fef6bbffff8
                                       Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

                                       Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
                                       Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
                                       Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

                                       VM Regions Near 0x7fef6bbffff8:
                                       Stack                  0000700002a04000-0000700002a86000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 8
                                       -->
                                       MALLOC_TINY            00007fef6bc00000-00007fef6c000000 [ 4096K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV

                                       Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
                                       0   libsystem_platform.dylib          0x00007fffe6b421c6 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem + 486
                                       1   com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd781c405 std::__1::vector<SKCNode*, std::__1::allocator<SKCNode*> >::insert(std::__1::__wrap_iter<SKCNode* const*>, SKCNode* const&) + 131
                                       2   com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd781c326 SKCNode::insertChildAtIndex(SKCNode*, int) + 294
                                       3   com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd784ffd2 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 294
                                       4   com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd784fe8b -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
                                       5   MF.Drum-Hero                      0x0000000105769cb9 0x105761000 + 36025
                                       6   MF.Drum-Hero                      0x0000000105769a48 0x105761000 + 35400
                                       7   MF.Drum-Hero                      0x0000000105769685 0x105761000 + 34437
                                       8   MF.Drum-Hero                      0x0000000105776724 0x105761000 + 87844
                                       9   com.apple.GameplayKit             0x00007fffd2a9975e -[GKStateMachine updateWithDeltaTime:] + 62
                                       10  MF.Drum-Hero                      0x000000010576ce44 0x105761000 + 48708
                                       11  com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd7823dd6 -[SKScene _update:] + 365
                                       12  com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd77cee6a -[SKView _update:] + 1156
                                       13  com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd77cb920 __51-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke.385 + 285
                                       14  com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd77cad17 -[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:] + 658
                                       15  com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd77ccc8e __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 291
                                       16  com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd784783f -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 324
                                       17  com.apple.SpriteKit               0x00007fffd7847a42 ___Z22_cvDisplayLinkCallbackP15__CVDisplayLinkPK11CVTimeStampS3_yPyPv_block_invoke + 36
                                       18  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fffe6906524 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
                                       19  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fffe68fd8fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
                                       20  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fffe690aaac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 925
                                       21  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c3fd69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
                                       22  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c0104d __CFRunLoopRun + 2221
                                       23  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c00544 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
                                       24  com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fffd015febc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
                                       25  com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fffd015fcf1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
                                       26  com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fffd015fb26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
                                       27  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fffce6f8a54 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
                                       28  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fffcee747ee -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
                                       29  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fffce6ed3db -[NSApplication run] + 926
                                       30  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fffce6b7e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
                                       31  libdyld.dylib                     0x00007fffe6933235 start + 1

                                       Thread 1:: CVDisplayLink
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a61bf2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
                                       1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4d833 _pthread_cond_wait + 769
                                       2   com.apple.CoreVideo               0x00007fffd22da977 CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 233
                                       3   com.apple.CoreVideo               0x00007fffd22da762 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 520
                                       4   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c93b _pthread_body + 180
                                       5   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c887 _pthread_start + 286
                                       6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c08d thread_start + 13

                                       Thread 2:: com.apple.NSEventThread
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a5a34a mach_msg_trap + 10
                                       1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a59797 mach_msg + 55
                                       2   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c01874 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
                                       3   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c00cf1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
                                       4   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c00544 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
                                       5   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fffce845f02 _NSEventThread + 205
                                       6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c93b _pthread_body + 180
                                       7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c887 _pthread_start + 286
                                       8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c08d thread_start + 13

                                       Thread 3:
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a6244e __workq_kernreturn + 10
                                       1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c621 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
                                       2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c07d start_wqthread + 13

                                       Thread 4:
                                       0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fffe6042cdb search_method_list(method_list_t const*, objc_selector*) + 107
                                       1   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fffe60450a5 lookUpImpOrForward + 383
                                       2   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fffe6044a94 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
                                       3   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fffd2615716 +[NSConcreteNotification newTempNotificationWithName:object:userInfo:] + 123
                                       4   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fffd261565f -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 42
                                       5   MF.Drum-Hero                      0x000000010576a413 0x105761000 + 37907
                                       6   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c1654c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
                                       7   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c1644b _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
                                       8   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c161b2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
                                       9   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0bd4782 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018
                                       10  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0bd376b _CFXNotificationPost + 667
                                       11  com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fffd2615677 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
                                       12  MF.Drum-Hero                      0x000000010576df60 0x105761000 + 53088
                                       13  MF.Drum-Hero                      0x000000010576de5f 0x105761000 + 52831
                                       14  MF.Drum-Hero                      0x000000010576dd34 0x105761000 + 52532
                                       15  com.apple.audio.midi.CoreMIDI     0x00000001057b6d5e LocalMIDIReceiverList::HandleMIDIIn(unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, MIDIPacketList const*) + 120
                                       16  com.apple.audio.midi.CoreMIDI     0x00000001057b6c12 MIDIProcess::RunMIDIInThread() + 210
                                       17  com.apple.audio.midi.CoreMIDI     0x00000001057c3a9a XThread::RunHelper(void*) + 10
                                       18  com.apple.audio.midi.CoreMIDI     0x00000001057c7053 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 85
                                       19  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c93b _pthread_body + 180
                                       20  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c887 _pthread_start + 286
                                       21  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c08d thread_start + 13

                                       Thread 5:: com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a5a34a mach_msg_trap + 10
                                       1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a59797 mach_msg + 55
                                       2   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c01874 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
                                       3   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c00cf1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
                                       4   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffd0c00544 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
                                       5   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fffcf9d1899 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 189
                                       6   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fffcf9d172b CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 85
                                       7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c93b _pthread_body + 180
                                       8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c887 _pthread_start + 286
                                       9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c08d thread_start + 13

                                       Thread 6:: AQConverterThread
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a61bf2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
                                       1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4d7fa _pthread_cond_wait + 712
                                       2   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fffcf9ff256 CAGuard::Wait() + 52
                                       3   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fffcf9f9f0d AQConverterManager::AQConverterThread::Run() + 707
                                       4   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fffcf9f9c3f AQConverterManager::AQConverterThread::ConverterThreadEntry(void*) + 9
                                       5   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fffcf9d172b CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 85
                                       6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c93b _pthread_body + 180
                                       7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c887 _pthread_start + 286
                                       8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c08d thread_start + 13

                                       Thread 7:: AudioStreamerImpl::sIOWorkerProcess
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a5a386 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
                                       1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fffe6915a77 _os_semaphore_wait + 16
                                       2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fffe6906891 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 103
                                       3   com.apple.audio.units.Components    0x0000000105e8ce25 CASemaphore::Wait() + 23
                                       4   com.apple.audio.units.Components    0x0000000105e8b94f AudioStreamerImpl::sIOWorkerProcess(void*) + 735
                                       5   com.apple.audio.units.Components    0x0000000105ed16e5 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 85
                                       6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c93b _pthread_body + 180
                                       7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c887 _pthread_start + 286
                                       8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c08d thread_start + 13

                                       Thread 8:: com.apple.audio.IOThread.client
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a5a34a mach_msg_trap + 10
                                       1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a59797 mach_msg + 55
                                       2   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd0769935 HALB_MachPort::SendMessageWithReply(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, mach_msg_header_t*, bool, unsigned int) + 127
                                       3   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd07698a6 HALB_MachPort::SendSimpleMessageWithSimpleReply(unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int&, bool, unsigned int) + 42
                                       4   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd07668d0 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop() + 1196
                                       5   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd0766264 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOThreadEntry(void*) + 128
                                       6   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd0765fa3 HALB_IOThread::Entry(void*) + 75
                                       7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c93b _pthread_body + 180
                                       8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c887 _pthread_start + 286
                                       9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c08d thread_start + 13

                                       Thread 9:
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a6244e __workq_kernreturn + 10
                                       1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c48e _pthread_wqthread + 1023
                                       2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c07d start_wqthread + 13

                                       Thread 10:
                                       0   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c070 start_wqthread + 0
                                       1   ???                               0x0000700002771ad0 0 + 123145343670992

                                       Thread 11:: com.apple.audio.IOThread.client
                                       0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a5a34a mach_msg_trap + 10
                                       1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fffe6a59797 mach_msg + 55
                                       2   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd0769935 HALB_MachPort::SendMessageWithReply(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, mach_msg_header_t*, bool, unsigned int) + 127
                                       3   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd07698a6 HALB_MachPort::SendSimpleMessageWithSimpleReply(unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int&, bool, unsigned int) + 42
                                       4   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd07668d0 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop() + 1196
                                       5   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd0766264 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOThreadEntry(void*) + 128
                                       6   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio         0x00007fffd0765fa3 HALB_IOThread::Entry(void*) + 75
                                       7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c93b _pthread_body + 180
                                       8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c887 _pthread_start + 286
                                       9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fffe6b4c08d thread_start + 13

                                       Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
                                       rax: 0x00007fef6bd94fd8  rbx: 0x00007fef6bd94fd8  rcx: 0x0000000000000008  rdx: 0xffffffffffe6b028
                                       rdi: 0x00007fef6bc00040  rsi: 0x00007fef6bc00038  rbp: 0x00007fff5a49c860  rsp: 0x00007fff5a49c860
                                       r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fffec5954f0  r10: 0x00007fffecee1b60  r11: 0x00007fef6bd94fc8
                                       r12: 0x00007fef720cd3e8  r13: 0x00007fef6bd95090  r14: 0x00007fef6bd94fd0  r15: 0x00007fff5a49c8f0
                                       rip: 0x00007fffe6b421c6  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x00007fef6bbffff8

                                       Logical CPU:     2
                                       Error Code:      0x00000004
                                       Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: Looks to me like your code may have a synchronous problem, because you are attempting to add a child that is null.  Basically the schools machines are at a different speed than your personal machine, so the order in which events happen are different.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The issue with the crash log is that it doesn't really show me where in my code that the synchronization issue is occurring. Or does it? All I see is `5   MF.Drum-Hero                      0x0000000105769cb9 0x105761000 + 36025`

Comment: it is somewhere in your update statement, it is not going to tell you what line of code it is,  you are going to have to run the app in XCode on your school machine

Comment: anywhere you addChild in your code,  I would check to make sure the node is not null  (maybe you should Swift-ify this code to make life easier)

Comment: Ok. I'll try running it on the school machines. I would "swift-ify" it, but I couldn't get the lower level MIDI C code working with Swift without errors when I first started this project. After reading Gene De Lisa's page, it seems that certain elements of handling MIDI are not yet supported with swift. Ugghhh...

Comment: you can still access the c code through bridging

Comment: Yeah probably. I just didn't know how to do it at the time. I'll try again when I work on a new project.

Comment: breakpoints is your friend. put it everywhere up to where you suspect it crashes. then do step one by one then you will find it.

Comment: Yup, I do this all the time. I think the main issue is what @Knight0fDragon suggested, which is to test it on the school machines. On my machine all objects initialize fine, but on the school machines there seems to be an issue.